# How to obtain the value of an expression from a range in SPARQL

Tags: range, sparql, owl, ontology, fuseki

I have an ontology with different classes and each class has a range with an expression. I'm attacking the ontology with Apache Jena Fuseki but when I execute the query to get the properties with their values I receive "b0" or "b1" instead of the expression of range (this expression could be "xsd:double[>= "0.0"^^xsd:double , <= "20000.0"^^xsd:double]")

The query is:

```
SELECT ?property ?range
WHERE {
?property rdfs:domain ns:Area;
          rdfs:range ?range.
}
```

And the result is

```
property                   range 
ns:isSubcapsularLocalized  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean> 
ns:hasAreaContrastPattern  _:b0
```

I want the query return the expression "xsd:double[>= "0.0"^^xsd:double , <= "20000.0"^^xsd:double]" instead of _:b0

Thanks!

Comment: SPARQL is not really designed for querying OWL ontologies given that complex expressions can be made of sets of triples usually even nested blank nodes and RDF collections (owl:unionOf, owl:intersectionOf) - of you know in advance that it's an OWL facet, you could check for the RDF mappings of OWL 2 and write the graph pattern. IF not, you're almost lost

Comment: Table 12 [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/) shows how DataRanges will be represented as triples. If you get lucky, SPARQL property paths can help to some extent